# Moved data from controller to factory, and can't get it from there

Tags: angularjs, factory

```
This is a shortened version of the js file

var linksManager = angular.module('linksManager', ['ui']);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['linksManager']);

linksManager.factory('linksData', function () {
    var linksData = [
        {
            text: 'Menu Item 1',
            url: '#'
        }, {
            text: 'Menu Item 2',
            url: '#',
            submenu: [
 // more data ...

});
```

function linksRarrange($scope, linksData) {
    $scope.links = linksData;
}

Before the `linksData` was directly inside the `linksRearrange` controller

```
$scope.links = [
        {
            text: 'Menu Item 1',
            url: '#'
        }, {
            text: 'Menu Item 2',
            url: '#',
            submenu: [
 // more data ...
```

And it worked fine, why the sharing doesn't work now?

This is the HTML, it doesn't display anything now:

```
<div class="nav-manage clearfix" ng-app="linksManager">

    <div class="links-arrange" ng-controller="linksRarrange">
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li ng-repeat="level1link in links">
                <a href="{{level1link.url}}">{{level1link.text}}</a>
                <ul class="sortable">
                    <li ng-repeat='level2link in level1link.submenu'>
                        <a href="{{level2link.url}}">{{level2link.text}}</a>
                        <ul class="sortable">
                            <li ng-repeat='level3link in link.level2link'>
                                <a href="{{level3link.url}}">{{level3link.text}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`factory` of angular is supposed to return the object.

I think you forgot to

```
return linksData;
```

at the end of the factory function.